# Choosing the correct upper and lower HSV boundaries for color detection with`cv::inRange` (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hsv, color-detection

I have an image of a coffee can with an orange lid position of which I want to find.
Here is it [image].

gcolor2 utility shows HSV at the center of the lid to be (22, 59, 100).
The question is how to choose the limits of the color then? I tried min = (18, 40, 90) and max = (27, 255, 255), but have got unexpected [image: result]

Here is the Python code:

```
import cv

in_image = 'kaffee.png'
out_image = 'kaffee_out.png'
out_image_thr = 'kaffee_thr.png'

ORANGE_MIN = cv.Scalar(18, 40, 90)
ORANGE_MAX = cv.Scalar(27, 255, 255)
COLOR_MIN = ORANGE_MIN
COLOR_MAX = ORANGE_MAX

def test1():
    frame = cv.LoadImage(in_image)
    frameHSV = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), 8, 3)
    cv.CvtColor(frame, frameHSV, cv.CV_RGB2HSV)
    frame_threshed = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frameHSV), 8, 1)
    cv.InRangeS(frameHSV, COLOR_MIN, COLOR_MAX, frame_threshed)
    cv.SaveImage(out_image_thr, frame_threshed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test1()
```

Comment: I checked the values (22, 59, 100) as HSV, and they don't seem to match the any color similar to the ones of the lid. But as BGR, they make sense. How did you retrieve these values?

Comment: Here is screenshot with gcolor2 http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/rgb2hsv.png/. I then checked color number #FFA069 on http://www.yafla.com/yaflaColor/ColorRGBHSL.aspx?RGB=&Colors=,,,,,,,,, and the conversion is the same.

Comment: This is probably due to different HSV ranges in OpenCV, namely H: 0 - 180, S: 0 - 255, V: 0 - 255.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

**Problem 1 :** Different applications use different scales for HSV. For example gimp uses `H = 0-360, S = 0-100 and V = 0-100`. But OpenCV uses  `H: 0-179, S: 0-255, V: 0-255`. Here i got a hue value of 22 in gimp. So I took half of it, 11, and defined range for that. ie `(5,50,50) - (15,255,255)`.

**Problem 2:** And also, OpenCV uses BGR format, not RGB. So change your code which converts RGB to HSV as follows:

```
cv.CvtColor(frame, frameHSV, cv.CV_BGR2HSV)
```

Now run it. I got an output as follows:

[image]

Hope that is what you wanted. There are some false detections, but they are small, so you can choose biggest contour which is your lid.

**EDIT:**

As **Karl Philip** told in his comment, it would be good to add new code. But there is change of only a single line. So, I would like to add the same code implemented in new `cv2` module, so users can compare the easiness and flexibility of new `cv2` module.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('sof.jpg')

ORANGE_MIN = np.array([5, 50, 50],np.uint8)
ORANGE_MAX = np.array([15, 255, 255],np.uint8)

hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, ORANGE_MIN, ORANGE_MAX)
cv2.imwrite('output2.jpg', frame_threshed)
```

It gives the same result as above. But code is much more simpler.

Comment: +1 Excellent, once again. If you could add the full source code with your modifications it would be awesome.

Comment: Thank you. But i don't think there is much excellency here.:) (OK, i will do it)

Comment: Great! It works for me now as well, although I believe your S and V min-max ranges are too relaxed. I also have got good lid coverage with min (5, 100, 255) and max (15, 200, 255).

Comment: Good to know. I took S,V values just to show the result, to show this solution works. Good you found better ones. Also try to move onto `cv2` interface. It is more simpler and faster. You can find some good tutorials here: opencvpython.blogspot.com. And if it solves your problem, accept the answer and close this session.

Comment: This is the place where every one commits mistakes when they are newbies to OpenCv.

Comment: I used this code to detect a green color line in an image.I gave the min and max (0,255,0).But nothing was detected.Does anyone know what happened there.

Comment: In terms of HSV, H (hue) is the color. If you use multiple images, you might need a fairly wide range for SV. Also, a color (pink for me) may wrap from the max value to zero.

Answer (score 102):

Ok, find color in `HSV` space is an old but common question. I made a `hsv-colormap` to fast look up special color. Here it is:

[image]

The x-axis represents `Hue` in [0,180), the y-axis1 represents `Saturation` in [0,255], the y-axis2 represents `S = 255`, while keep `V = 255`.

To find a color, usually just look up for the range of `H` and `S`, and set v in range(20, 255).

To find the orange color, we look up for the map, and find the best range: `H :[10, 25], S: [100, 255], and V: [20, 255]`. So the mask is `cv2.inRange(hsv,(10, 100, 20), (25, 255, 255) )`

Then we use the found range to look for the orange color, this is the result:

[image]

---

The method is simple but common to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.21 20:46:41 CST
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,(10, 100, 20), (25, 255, 255) )
cv2.imshow("orange", mask);cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Similar answers:

> 1. [How to define a threshold value to detect only green colour objects in an image :Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966)
> 2. [Choosing correct HSV values for OpenCV thresholding with InRangeS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-correct-hsv-values-for-opencv-thresholding-with-inranges/48367205#48367205)

Comment: second link behaving oddly?

Comment: @jtlz2: They simply linked back to *this answer*. Perhaps in mistake.

Comment: A bit late but wondering how you determined the V value. In my application I'm using histograms to determine H/S values but wasn't sure about V. Regarding 0-100% being dark/light I guess in a decently lit room we'd just go for a median value?

Answer (score 80):

Here's a simple HSV color thresholder script to determine the lower/upper color ranges using trackbars for any image on the disk. Simply change the image path in `cv2.imread()`. Example to isolate orange:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

# Load image
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('image')

# Create trackbars for color change
# Hue is from 0-179 for Opencv
cv2.createTrackbar('HMin', 'image', 0, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMin', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMin', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('HMax', 'image', 0, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMax', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMax', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)

# Set default value for Max HSV trackbars
cv2.setTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image', 179)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image', 255)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image', 255)

# Initialize HSV min/max values
hMin = sMin = vMin = hMax = sMax = vMax = 0
phMin = psMin = pvMin = phMax = psMax = pvMax = 0

while(1):
    # Get current positions of all trackbars
    hMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMin', 'image')
    sMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMin', 'image')
    vMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMin', 'image')
    hMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image')
    sMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image')
    vMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image')

    # Set minimum and maximum HSV values to display
    lower = np.array([hMin, sMin, vMin])
    upper = np.array([hMax, sMax, vMax])

    # Convert to HSV format and color threshold
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    # Print if there is a change in HSV value
    if((phMin != hMin) | (psMin != sMin) | (pvMin != vMin) | (phMax != hMax) | (psMax != sMax) | (pvMax != vMax) ):
        print("(hMin = %d , sMin = %d, vMin = %d), (hMax = %d , sMax = %d, vMax = %d)" % (hMin , sMin , vMin, hMax, sMax , vMax))
        phMin = hMin
        psMin = sMin
        pvMin = vMin
        phMax = hMax
        psMax = sMax
        pvMax = vMax

    # Display result image
    cv2.imshow('image', result)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

HSV lower/upper color threshold ranges

```
(hMin = 0 , sMin = 164, vMin = 0), (hMax = 179 , sMax = 255, vMax = 255)
```

Once you have determined your `lower` and `upper` HSV color ranges, you can segment your desired colors like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 164, 0])
upper = np.array([179, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful.  Made figuring out an appropriate HSV range 20x faster.  Many mahalos!

Comment: Wow! Extremely helpful as commented already. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Pure awesomeness! Thank you very much

Comment: Just want to echo the above comments and say that this colorpicker is amazing. Super helpful for getting 90% of the way to accurate HSV thresholding, many many thanks.

Comment: Amazingly useful, thanks so much for this!

Comment: Very useful. Saved a ton of time. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 33):

I Created this simple program to get HSV Codes in realtime

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def nothing(x):
    pass
# Creating a window for later use
cv2.namedWindow('result')

# Starting with 100's to prevent error while masking
h,s,v = 100,100,100

# Creating track bar
cv2.createTrackbar('h', 'result',0,179,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('s', 'result',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('v', 'result',0,255,nothing)

while(1):

    _, frame = cap.read()

    #converting to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # get info from track bar and appy to result
    h = cv2.getTrackbarPos('h','result')
    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos('s','result')
    v = cv2.getTrackbarPos('v','result')

    # Normal masking algorithm
    lower_blue = np.array([h,s,v])
    upper_blue = np.array([180,255,255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_blue, upper_blue)

    result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask = mask)

    cv2.imshow('result',result)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: LOL, I had written same code with printing the final HSV values used https://github.com/saurabheights/ImageProcessingExperimentScripts/blob/master/AnalyzeHSV/hsvThresholder.py

Answer (score 10):

I created a simple (more proper) tool using opencv-python for this purpose. Thought it would be useful for someone stumbled here like I did earlier this year

[image]

Since the tool itself is written using python cv2, it would be guaranteed to use the same range. Also there's a slider for `erode` and `dilate` since usually computer vision project need these two feature

You can clone the tool from here https://github.com/hariangr/HsvRangeTool

Comment: awesome tool, thanks for sharing, what does the copy button does?, I was expecting to copy the values

Comment: @JoeCabezas I completely forgot about the button, I just implemented it to print the hsv range to console. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

OpenCV HSV range is:
H: 0 to 179
S: 0 to 255
V: 0 to 255

On Gimp (or other photo manipulation sw) Hue range from 0 to 360, since opencv put color info in a single byte, the maximum number value in a single byte is 255 therefore openCV Hue values are equivalent to Hue values from gimp divided by 2.

I found when trying to do object detection based on HSV color space that a range of 5 (opencv range) was sufficient to filter out a specific color. I would advise you to use an HSV color palate to figure out the range that works best for your application.

[image: HSV color palate with color detection in HSV space]

Answer (score 6):

To find the HSV value of Green, try following commands in Python terminal

```
green = np.uint8([[[0,255,0 ]]])
hsv_green = cv2.cvtColor(green,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print hsv_green
[[[ 60 255 255]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GIMP or PaintDotNet to get the exact range of HSV. But the problem is that the HSV range in graphics software is different from the same range in OpenCV, so you need a function to correct this for you. For this purpose, you can use the following function.

```py
def fixHSVRange(h, s, v):
    # Normal H,S,V: (0-360,0-100%,0-100%)
    # OpenCV H,S,V: (0-180,0-255 ,0-255)
    return (180 * h / 360, 255 * s / 100, 255 * v / 100)
```

[image]

For example you can use it something like this:

```py
im=cv2.imread("image.jpg",1)
im_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
color1 = fixHSVRange(h=10, s=20, v=0)
color2 = fixHSVRange(h=30, s=70, v=100)
mask = cv2.inRange(im_hsv, color1, color2)
cv2.imwrite("mask.jpg",mask)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of the methods mentioned above usually require some knowledge of the colour range for a particular colour followed by trial and error to get the right range. But the official documentation of OpenCV suggests a better way to find HSV lower and upper bounds even for the colours that are not very common.

> #### How to find HSV values to track?
>
> This is a common question found in stackoverflow.com. It is very simple and you can use the same function, cv.cvtColor(). Instead of passing an image, you just pass the BGR values you want. For example, to find the HSV value of Green, try the following commands in a Python terminal:

You can find the exact pixel values (BGR) of the required object and use them for example green (0, 255, 0)

```py
green = np.uint8([[[0,255,0 ]]])
hsv_green = cv.cvtColor(green,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print(hsv_green)
```

```
[[[60 255 255]]]
```

> Now you take **[H-10, 100,100]** and **[H+10, 255, 255]** as the lower bound and upper bound respectively. Apart from this method, you can use any image editing tools like GIMP or any online converters to find these values, but don't forget to adjust the HSV ranges.

Source:
[OpenCV Colorspaces and Object Tracking](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html)
[GIMP - Image Manipulating Tool](https://www.gimp.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling to find what HSV values to choose (to ultimately select regions). With quite some googling I made this small script to inspect HSV values in my image.

It opens your image (adjust the path at `cv2.imread`).
When you click at a point of interest in the image, it prints the location of mouse-click and HSV values at that location in the image.

```
import cv2

def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        print("HSV values at ({}, {}): {}".format(x, y, hsv[y, x]))

img = cv2.imread(‘\path\to\your\image\piccie.png’)
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", on_mouse)

while True:
    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```