# The Result Of Function "cvtColor" of OpenCV

Tags: opencv, rgb, hsv

I try to convert a RGB image to HSV color space, and get the HSV value of a pixel.
But the result is a little strange, as far as I know, the range of H is between 0 and 360, S and　V is between 0 to 255, but the result that I have got is 0~255 for any of HSV value. I doubt that OpenCV have done the transform, is that right? Please help me.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-correct-hsv-values-for-opencv-thresholding-with-inranges). The H range in opencv is not what you think.

Answer (score 0):

If you're acquaint with the RGB-HSV conversion, OpenCV uses the following formulas to convert B,G,R values, (0~255) to H,S,V:

V=Max(B,G,R)

S=255*[1-min(B,G,R)/Max(B,G,R)]

let d=Max(B,G,R)-min(B,G,R)

H=30*[((G-B)/d)%6] if V=R

=30*[((B-R)/d)+2] if V=G

=30*[((R-G)/d)+4] if V=B