# getting started on android openCV

Tags: android, opencv

I'm very new to Android and Java programming, but I want to start to develop some apps. I already have installed Eclipse, Android SDK and Open CV and I am able to compile the samples, but I can't understand how they work, because it's very different to C/C++, which I know something. I tried to find something on internet, but I don't find many tutorials for beginners.
What I would like to make now is an app that identifies shapes and colors. For example, if I choose yellow circles, the app will highlight the yellow circles . For first I will print this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcox6.png) on paper and try to identify using my smartphone.

PS: Sorry about my English.

Comment: You can start from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32077775/5008845), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424002/how-to-detect-simple-geometric-shapes-using-opencv) and [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/). You should start googling stuff, and come back on StackOverflow when you have actual programming problems

Answer (score 0):

[There is a great article](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/) just for your question, but it is on AForge.NET framework. Despite that, information here may lead you to a proper path or approach.

If I were you using OpenCV I would do these steps to solve this problem:

- **At first, I would extract the shapes of different colors.** There is a function for that called `InRange` (maybe some help about this you may find in the question and my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357141/identifying-green-circles-from-this-image/38357999#38357999). Extracted shapes of different colors should be stored in differend Mat objects, f.e. shapes for yellow stored in one Mat, blue in another and so on. Seperating different color shapes by this extraction would be easier for the following processing.
- **After that the contour finding should follow.** It could be done either with `Canny` or `findContours` functions, but the second one would be prefered because after `InRange` your image will be binary (mask). Then, every shape should be stored in seperate Mat object, drawing them using `drawContours` function. It should me a multidimentional array or so, because at first your shapes should be sorted by color.
- **Then, easiest thing is finding the circles**. This could be done simply with `houghCircles` function. This function may misunderstand pentagons with circles, but using proper parameters it should work perfectly. More info [HERE](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/21/detecting-circles-images-using-opencv-hough-circles/). Now you know which shapes are circles and their color.
- **At the end is finding the rest of the shapes and their types.** This would not be easy. ***FIRST*** way (I'd try it first probably) would be simplifying your contours with `approxPolyDP` function. Then, for the sake of precision you could use `convexHull`. After that, if needed, check each lines degree of angle with the following line, so you could find lines which together form a, lets say, ~182-178 degrees (almost a straight line). Those lines should be merged into one, because that is an error of contour simplifying. Check how many lines the shape (or simplified contour) has and that is the type of shape. ***SECOND*** method would be finding a `houghLines` on contours. Then, checking the collisions of each line with another to find how many of them are here and forming a shape having this data. More information [HERE](http://blog.ayoungprogrammer.com/2013/04/tutorial-detecting-multiple-rectangles.html/).

As you understood from my text, this task will not be easy for sure. Using any approach it will not be easy, but this is possible for sure, it is quite a common task, much information can be found about this.