# How to find the correct HSV threshold values of an object for OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

I am trying to find the correct lowerbounds/upperbounds threshold values of a ball, so that I can use it in the OpenCV `inRange` function.

I've read [Choosing correct HSV values for OpenCV thresholding with InRangeS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-correct-hsv-values-for-opencv-thresholding-with-inranges), but I still dont understand how to do this in my case:

[image]

**inRange function:**

```
inRange(frmHsv, Scalar(lowerH, lowerS, lowerV), Scalar(upperH, upperS, upperV), rangeRes);
```

**OpenCV HSV ranges:**

H: 0 - 180

S: 0 - 255

V: 0 - 255

How can I find `lowerH`, `lowerS`, `lowerV`, `upperH`, `upperS`, `upperV`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look of this tutorial is really good!

It create a trackbar to move the upper and lower value online and check what is the best response for your object. I used for a cylinder color coded detection and works really well.

http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html

Comment: Thank you, this tool is what I was looking for! :)