# Detect contour points from color shapes

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

Please refer attached image. The image has many polygons with different colors. I need to find contour points(ordered) of polygon with specified color. I need to do this in OpenCV. I am new to OpenCV and I looked at various references on internet but they are in some way different from my problem mentioned here. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, I am going to give you the one I would use.

**Extracting binary image of desired colour**

In order to focus on a specific colour you may try RGB/HSV thresholding setting top and lower boundaries for a specific colour. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv) you can find a nice answer on how to do that.

**Extracting contour from binary image**

For that you can use findContours() function form OpenCV. It is based on a work of [Suzuki and Abe](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Topological-structural-analysis-of-digitized-binary-Suzuki-Abe/e9f21d440f9317fc8b6c294b9826b70ad5312d36) as well as on Moore pixel following algorithm. If you want to know more you can find a more detailed description in documentation of the function.

**Arrange contour points as you wish**

findCountours() will give you an array of contour points, you can rearrange them in any order you wish.

Hope that will help, good luck!

Comment: Hello Болат Тлеубаев, Thanks for the answer. I found two more links based on your suggestions - https://pysource.com/2018/03/01/find-and-draw-contours-opencv-3-4-with-python-3-tutorial-19/ and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/20/sorting-contours-using-python-and-opencv/