# Color thresholding: Why does mask make a drastic difference according to limits specified?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-masking, image-thresholding

We want to apply color thresholding to a RGB image:

[image: original image]

When we specify the lower limit as `[0, 0, 0]` and the upper limit as `[255, 255, 255]` the result is as follows:

[image: mask with 0]

And, when the lower limit is `[1, 1, 1]` and the upper limit is `[255, 255, 255]` the result is as follows:

[image: mask with 1]

Why does the difference of one pixel make such a drastic change in masking?

Code:

```
lower_blue = np.array([0,0,0]) 
upper_blue = np.array([255,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(image_copy, lower_blue, upper_blue)
plt.imshow(mask,cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here: _**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question._ Please provide a [mre]. Do you have any other (pre) processing steps not shown here?

Comment: When you load the image, check whether you are loading the alpha channel too...

Comment: Apologies @HansHirse it was my first time... but the images were necessary for the understanding...

Comment: @MarkSetchell there is no alpha channel. The masking usually selects the range to be passed and change the mask area to black... but why can sudden change from lower limit from 0 to 1 change the mask so much?

Comment: What is the shape of your image after you load it `image.shape` please?

Comment: Please provide the **actual** image you open and analyse rather than a plot/screengrab of it. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell apologies for the mistake.. I have attached the original image. The image shape is (514, 816, 3)
I need to mask the blue  screen.. but for general extra information, I wanted to know why this happens.

Comment: Just use lower_blue=(11,36,251) and upper_blue=(11,36,251), since those are the constant R,G,B values for your blue background. Or vary it just a bit such as lower_blue=(0,0,240) and upper_blue=(20,50,255), if the blue was not constant.

Comment: When you use ranges of (0,0,0) and (255,255,255) you are including every possible color -- all value from 0-255 in each of the red, green and blue channels of your image. When you have just blues, then limit the ranges to just a narrow set of of values below and above the red, green and blue values for your blue color as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Your main "problem" is Matplotlib's [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) function here.

In your first case, you just mask ALL pixels in your image, such that all pixels in `mask` have value `255`. When using `imshow` without any parameters on such images, an automatic color scaling is applied, such that the corresponding plot is set to `0` for all pixels, since all pixels have the same value. If you explicitly set `vmin` and `vmax` (see linked documentation page) in the `imshow` call, you see the expected all white plot.

The minor changes in your second case cause some pixels in `mask` to be `0`, such that even the standard `imshow` call will produce the "correct" color scaling, since the pixels in `mask` cover the whole "range" `[0 ... 255]`, because there are only pixel values of `0` and `255`.

Now, to detect the blue background: In your case, the blue background seems to have a fixed RGB value, so using OpenCV's [`inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) with the standard BGR image might be appropriate. In general, for color masking, converting the image to the HSV/HSL color space is more sophisticated - from my point of view. For a short introduction, picking the proper `H`, `S`, `L` values, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55827176/11089932) I made on an earlier question.

I made some code for the above-mentioned comparisons, and for the actual detecting of the blue background:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('8au0O.jpg')

lower_blue = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper_blue = np.array([255, 255, 255])
mask_lb000 = cv2.inRange(image, lower_blue, upper_blue)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(mask_lb000, cmap='gray')
plt.title('imshow without explicit vmin, vmax')
plt.subplot(2, 3, 4)
plt.imshow(mask_lb000, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.title('imshow with explicit vmin, vmax')

lower_blue = np.array([1, 1, 1])
upper_blue = np.array([255, 255, 255])
mask_lb111 = cv2.inRange(image, lower_blue, upper_blue)

plt.subplot(2, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(mask_lb111, cmap='gray')
plt.title('imshow without explicit vmin, vmax')
plt.subplot(2, 3, 5)
plt.imshow(mask_lb111, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.title('imshow with explicit vmin, vmax')

# Detect blue-ish areas in HSL converted image
# H value must be appropriate (see HSL color space), e.g. within [200 ... 260]
# L value can be arbitrary (we want everything between bright and dark blue), e.g. within [0.0 ... 1.0]
# S value must be above some threshold (we want at least some saturation), e.g. within [0.35 ... 1.0]
lower_blue = np.array([np.round(200 / 2), np.round(0.00 * 255), np.round(0.35 * 255)])
upper_blue = np.array([np.round(260 / 2), np.round(1.00 * 255), np.round(1.00 * 255)])
mask_lb = cv2.inRange(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV), lower_blue, upper_blue)

plt.subplot(2, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(mask_lb, cmap='gray')
plt.title('imshow without explicit vmin, vmax')
plt.subplot(2, 3, 6)
plt.imshow(mask_lb, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.title('imshow with explicit vmin, vmax')

plt.show()
```

This is the generated output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!