# Insert the picture into the frame

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have a beautiful frame, and the image that needs to be inserted into this frame.

[image: Frame]

This frame

[image]

This image

Python code

```py
frame = Image.open("pathToFirstImage")
image = Image.open("pathToSecondImage")

frame.paste(image, (0,0))
frame.show()
frame.save("output image path")
```

How to Insert an image, framed by the red outline.

The contour angles are known. (I looked in photoshop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm skeptical that this task can be achieved by only using PIL/Pillow, at least if you want some automatic finding of the red frame, etc.

So, if using OpenCV is an option, I would suggest the following solution using some color thresholding and [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0). This approach should be also transferable to skimage for example.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io      # Only needed for web grabbing images; use cv2.imread(...) for local images

# Read images
frame = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVf0a.png'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
image = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw5Rc.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Color threshold red frame; single color here, more sophisticated solution would be using cv2.inRange
mask = 255 * np.uint8(np.all(frame == [36, 28, 237], axis=2))

# Find inner contour of frame; get coordinates
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = min(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

# Copy appropriately resized image to frame
frame[y:y+h, x:x+w] = cv2.resize(image, (w, h))

cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As stated in the comment, color thresholding in this example is done by simply checking for the specific BGR value of the frame. A more sophisticated solution would be converting the frame to the HSV/HSL color space, and then using [`cv2.inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981). For an introduction on that, please see [one of my earlier answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55827176/11089932).

The output of the above script looks like this:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!