# How to calculate the distance between two lines?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, distance

I have been trying to calculate the distance between two lines in an image in Python. For example, in the image given below, I want to find the perpendicular distance between the two ends of the yellow block. So far I have been only able to derive the distance between two pixels.

[image: Image of engine]

The code I could make was to find the distance between red and blue pixels. I figured I could improve this to make the distance between the two points/lines in this image, but no luck yet.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import math

# Load image and ensure RGB - just in case palettised
im = Image.open("2points.png").convert("RGB")

# Make numpy array from image
npimage = np.array(im)

# Describe what a single red pixel looks like
red = np.array([255,0,0],dtype=np.uint8)

# Find [x,y] coordinates of all red pixels
reds = np.where(np.all((npimage==red),axis=-1))

print(reds)

# Describe what a single blue pixel looks like
blue=np.array([0,0,255],dtype=np.uint8)

# Find [x,y] coordinates of all blue pixels
blues=np.where(np.all((npimage==blue),axis=-1))

print(blues)

dx2 = (blues[0][0]-reds[0][0])**2          # (200-10)^2
dy2 = (blues[1][0]-reds[1][0])**2          # (300-20)^2
distance = math.sqrt(dx2 + dy2)
print(distance)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65841870/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Maybe you could add a second, annotated image showing exactly what you want to find because it is not very clear what *"the perpendicular distance between the ends of the yellow block* means, given that there are at least 2 and maybe 5 yellow blocks and you don't state what it needs to be perpendicular to.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Its just the big yellow block in the middle

Comment: So you want the height of the largest yellow rectangle?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes. Height and Width.

Comment: Any reason not to use **OpenCV** which would be simpler?

Comment: Is this a learning exercise because there is no real need to write Python for this as it's a one-liner in Terminal with **ImageMagick**?

Comment: Also highly suggesting OpenCV for that: Color threshold the image on yellow, find contours, get the largest contour, [`cv2.boxPoints`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf78d467e024b4d7936cf9397185d2f5c), and you have width and height.

Comment: @HansHirse I have been trying to work on your suggestion and got started with OpenCV. I managed to learn about contours but I am not able to implement them to extract the largest contour here (yellow). I worked out the boxpoints part separately. Could you help me out here please

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have started with OpenCV and i am trying to implement it. Still not successful though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While preparing this answer, I realized, that my hint regarding [`cv2.boxPoints`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf78d467e024b4d7936cf9397185d2f5c) was misleading. Of course, I had [`cv2.boundingRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7) on my mind – sorry for that!

Nevertheless, here's the full step-by-step approach:

1. Use [`cv2.inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) to mask all yellow pixels. Attention: Your image has JPG artifacts, such that you get a lot of noise in the mask, cf. the output:

[image: Mask]

2. Use [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) to find all contours in the mask. That'll be over 50, due to the many tiny artifacts.
3. Use Python's [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function on the (list of) found contours using [`cv2.contourArea`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1) as key to get the largest contour.
4. Finally, use [`cv2.boundingRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7) to get the bounding rectangle of the contour. That's a tuple `(x, y, widht, height)`. Just use the last two elements, and you have your desired information.

That'd be my code:

```py
import cv2

# Read image with OpenCV
img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.ext')

# Mask yellow color (0, 255, 255) in image; Attention: OpenCV uses BGR ordering
yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(img, (0, 255, 255), (0, 255, 255))

# Find contours in yellow mask w.r.t the OpenCV version
cnts = cv2.findContours(yellow_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Get the largest contour
cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Get width and height from bounding rectangle of largest contour
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
print('Width:', w, '| Height:', h)
```

The output

```
Width: 518 | Height: 320
```

seems reasonable.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Worked out great and I approved your answer :) Quick question, how can I make changes to the range to find other colours, e.g. blue, red and other shades?

Comment: @UrmiBose In the `cv2.inRange` call, put the corresponding RGB values of the desired color. Attention: Please use RGB values only, if you have clean, single value colors like pure green `(0, 255, 0)` for example. If you want to detect "all green colors", switch to the HSV color space and use proper ranges, cf. [this earlier answer from me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55827176/11089932) for a starting point.