# cv2 Error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pycharm

I'm trying to filter red color in my images but I got an error which is
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ttbyx0jz\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed .
I have no idea how can I fix this. Here is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


path = "C:\\Users\\MERYEM\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\scan\\Img_Data\\Chosen\\frame3802.jpg"

image = cv2.imread(path)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_red = np.array([178,179,0])
upper_red = np.array([255,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_red, upper_red)

cv2.imshow('Original Image',image)
cv2.imshow('Detection', hsv)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I need you help, thanks in advance. Btw, I am using PyCharm if it matters

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Are you sure you are using an RGB image, and not YUV or grayscale?  And are you really sure those are legitimate HSV values?

Comment: The error message says that the image is not read. Make sure you have entered the correct path of the image. There is no other reason for this error message.

Comment: HSV range for opencv is (0-180, 0-255, 0-255) by the way.

Comment: @TimRoberts hey. I took this code from a youtube channel and I just edited the path. I'm sure that the path is correct however it does not work. Tim, which editor do you use? Maybe this is an editor issue, idk

Comment: That's hard to imagine. [255,255,255] is not a valid HSV.  Have you taken even the simplest debugging steps to print each and every value after you create it, to narrow things down?

Answer (score 0):

Check the image address again or select another image for test.

Also; [**HSV**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10951189/2227070) range for OpenCV is **(0-180, 0-255, 0-255)**

```py
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np


im = cv2.imread(sys.path[0]+'/back.png')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
redL = np.array([180*350/360, 0, 0])
redU = np.array([180*360/360, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, redL, redU)


mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.imwrite(sys.path[0]+'/out.png',np.hstack((im, mask)))
```

Output of image and output mask:

[image]

---

More information about modules and their licenses:
[OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv), [NumPy](https://numpy.org/about/)

Comment: Hello @Shamshirsaz.Navid, I tried another image and I got the same error. Also, I tried your code and I got the same error :'(. I'm sure that the path is correct

Comment: that is weird :) can you test it in another machine?

Comment: my friend tested it on her computer, however it did not work again. she uses vsc btw

Comment: What error does the code I wrote give you? I tested this code and it works fine :) Did you install the required modules?

Comment: Hello, I found why it did not work. Because my photos is included in OneDrive, it does not work and gives error. When I download new photo, It works because it is not in OneDrive. Thanks for your answers and interest. Appreciated