# How to define boundaries for HSV color in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was trying to perform image segmentation using color space. For example, rustic region. I wasn't sure how to select the boundaries for `cv2.inRange()`.

```
img = cv2.imread(file)
img_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_bound = np.array([0,70,70])
upper_bound = np.array([20,200,150])
mask0 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_bound, upper_bound)

lower_bound = np.array([170,70,70])
upper_bound = np.array([180,200,150])
mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_bound, upper_bound)

# add both masks
mask = mask0+mask1

output_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)
```

Comment: Is it like your mask should segment only the rustic region?

Comment: @NishaniKasineshan Yes, only the rustic region

Comment: You can find color charts with values for Hue channel online. In opencv the original hue rangeof 0..360 is mapped to 0..180. Understand HSV to choose S and V.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ad/HueScale.svg/1280px-HueScale.svg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to segment only the rusty part and not the other ones i tried some code as follow.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("rust1.png",1)
img_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_bound = np.array([120, 80, 0],dtype="uint8")
upper_bound = np.array([255, 255, 80],dtype="uint8")
mask0 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_bound, upper_bound)
cv2.imshow("mask",mask0)
output_img1 = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask0)

lower_bound = np.array([100,50,50])
upper_bound = np.array([205,205,88])
mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_bound, upper_bound)
output_img2 = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask1)
cv2.imshow("mask1",mask1)

final = cv2.bitwise_or(output_img1, output_img2)

cv2.imshow("rust",np.hstack([img,final]))[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great! May I know how you chose the boundaries? e.g. [120, 80, 0], [255, 255, 80]

Comment: @Eden Just play with those HSV range.Normal HSV range:H = 0-360, S = 0-100 and V = 0-100. Opencv HSV range: H: 0-179, S: 0-255, V: 0-255.Different applications use different scales for HSV. Refer similar problem[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv)

Comment: Thank you so much