# Color detect with real-time object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I am trying to do a chess-piece detection with tensorflow. Due to the task it's not possible to train the model with different color from the start cause in the real world senario the chess-piece may come in with unseen color. So what I have done now is training the model with six different label. The output is good. But my next step is how to do the color detection on each bounding box on each chess piece. I really don't have any idea how could i do that.

[The Progress should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qabc.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TunaCake, you can use YOLO, [example-1](https://github.com/hrithikacharukula/Chess-Pawn-Detection-using-YOLOv5-), [example-2](https://github.com/Liisjak/Chess-Object-Detection-YOLOv4)

Comment: @Bilal I have done chess piece detection task. The problem here is how to determine chess color

Comment: @TunaCake please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48367205)