# Remove everything of a specific color (with a color variation tolerance) from an image with Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, python-imaging-library

I have some text in blue #00a2e8, and some text in black on a PNG image (white background).

**How to remove everything in blue (including text in blue) on an image with Python PIL or OpenCV, with a certain tolerance for the variations of color?**

Indeed, every pixel of the text is not perfectly of the same color, there are variations, shades of blue.

Here is what I was thinking:

- convert from RGB to HSV
- find the Hue `h0` for the blue
- do a Numpy mask for Hue in the interval `[h0-10, h0+10]`
- set these pixels to white

Before coding this, is there a more standard way to do this with PIL or OpenCV Python?

Example [PNG file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwP8M.png): `foo` and `bar` blocks should be removed

[image]

Comment: did you just ask how to use `cv.inRange`?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/

Comment: What will be left when you *"remove"* blue? Will there be black? Or white? Or transparency?

Comment: @MarkSetchell White color. Thanks if you have an idea! Example PNG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwP8M.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your image has some issues. Firstly, it has a completely superfluous alpha channel which can be ignored. Secondly, the colours around your blues are quite a long way from blue!

I used your planned approach and found the removal was pretty poor:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('nwP8M.png')

# Define lower and upper limits of our blue
BlueMin = np.array([90,  200, 200],np.uint8)
BlueMax = np.array([100, 255, 255],np.uint8)

# Go to HSV colourspace and get mask of blue pixels
HSV  = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(HSV, BlueMin, BlueMax)

# Make all pixels in mask white
im[mask>0] = [255,255,255]
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-plainMask.png', im)
```

That gives this:

[image]

If you broaden the range, to get the rough edges, you start to affect the green letters, so instead I dilated the mask so that pixels *spatially* near the blues are made white as well as pixels *chromatically* near the blues:

```
# Try dilating (enlarging) mask with 3x3 structuring element
SE   = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)

# Make all pixels in mask white
im[mask>0] = [255,255,255]
cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

That gets you this:

[image]

You may wish to diddle with the actual values for your other images, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Perfect!
Side-remark: is `inRange` really different than doing numpy array filtering directly like `img[ (hsv[:,:,0]>h0) & (hsv[:,:,0]<h1) & (hsv[:,:,1]>s0) & (hsv[:,:,1]<s1) & (hsv[:,:,2]>v0) & (hsv[:,:,2]<v1)] = [255, 255, 255]`?

Comment: That is pretty much what it is doing but it will be coded in highly efficient SIMD instructions and will likely be considerably faster than Numpy.

Comment: @Basj I have added my answer with a different approach

Comment: Aren't the values of `BlueMin` and `BlueMax` defined in terms of RGB? So how were you able to use them in the HSV-transformed version?

Comment: @RaleighL. Good question, but they are defined in HSV space. Look at this diagram https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#/media/File:Hsv-polar-coord-hue-chroma.svg and you can see blue is around 180..200 but OpenCV uses a range of 0..180 in order to fit 360 degrees in uint8, so you hakve the actual degrees and get 90..100 as I used. The Sat and Value are both high so I used 200..255.

Comment: *"hakve"* = *"halve"* in previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to chime in with a different approach. My basic idea is convert the image from BGR to [LAB color space](https://www.xrite.com/blog/lab-color-space) and figure out if I can isolate the regions in blue. This can be done by focusing on the b-component of LAB, since it represents the color from yellow to blue.

**Code**

```
img = cv2.imread('image_path', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
b_component = lab[:,:,2]
```

(***Note:*** The blue regions are actually quite darker such that it can be isolated easily.)

[image]

```
th = cv2.threshold(b_component,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

But after applying threshold, the image contains some unwanted white pixels around the regions containing numeric text, which we do not want to consider.

[image]

To avoid the unwanted regions I tried out the following:

- Find contours above a certain area and draw each of them on 2-channel mask
- Mask out rectangular bounding box area for each contour.
- Locate pixels within that bounding box area that are 255 (white) on the threshold image
- Change those pixel values to white on the original PNG image.

In code below:

```
# finding contours
contours = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# initialize a mask of image shape and make copy of original image
black = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), np.uint8)
res = img.copy()

# draw only contours above certain area on the mask
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if int(area) > 200:
            cv2.drawContours(black, [c], 0, 255, -1)
```

If you see the following mask, it has enclosed all pixels within the contour in white. However, the pixels within the word "bar" should **not** be considered.

[image]

To isolate only the region with blue pixels, we perform "AND" operation with the threshold image `th`

```
mask = cv2.bitwise_and(th, th, mask = black)
```

[image]

We got the mask we actually want. The regions that are white in `mask` are made white in the copy of the original image `res`:

```
res[mask == 255] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
```

[image]

But the above image is **not** perfect. There are some regions still visible around the edges of the word foo.

In the following we dilate `mask` and repeat.

```
res = img.copy()
kernel_ellipse = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel_ellipse, iterations=1) 
res[dilate == 255] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
```

[image]

> ***Note:*** Using the A and B components of LAB color space you can isolate different colors quite easily, without having to spend time searching for the range. Colors with nearby shading and saturation can also be segmented.

Comment: Trackbars again might be useful here.

Comment: @fmw42 yes agree

Comment: not reproducable

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the function inRange:

```
thresh = 5
bgr = [255 - thresh, thresh , thresh ]
minBGR = np.array([bgr[0] - thresh, bgr[1] - thresh, bgr[2] - thresh])
maxBGR = np.array([bgr[0] + thresh, bgr[1] + thresh, bgr[2] + thresh])
maskBGR = cv2.inRange(image, minBGR, maxBGR)
resultBGR = cv2.bitwise_or(image, maskBGR)
```

Comment: Thanks @duloren. Which `bgr` and `thresh` would you use for this example? https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwP8M.png The color to remove is hex #00a2e8. Would you have an example adapted to this case?