# Removing false detected circles on pool table

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection, hough-transform, canny-operator

I am trying to make a program that will accept an image of a pool table and detect balls with OpenCV and Python. My algorithm right now is basically: 1) grayscaling the image; 2) applying median blur; 3) applying Gaussian blur; 4) applying `cv2.HoughCircles()` to detect circles.

Unfortunately, `cv2.HoughCircles()` detects random circles in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWnA8.jpg):

[image: Pool Table with Poor Circles Detection]

When I called `cv2.Canny()` to see the edges used in `cv2.HoughCircles`, the results included a lot of [noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3GBI.jpg) (due to the color/texture of the carpet):

[image: Canny Edge Detection on Pool Table]

How should I remove the false detected circles? Changing the values of "param2" to increase the accumulator threshold will cause the black eight ball to not be detected. I'm thinking of either 1) applying a mask to filter out everything but the pool table (and then determining a ROI from the mask); 2) applying a rectangle detection algorithm to detect the pool table; 3) applying [fiducials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker) to try an determine an ROI from the image.

Here is the original [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwWGf.jpg).

The code is below:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("Assets/Setup.jpg", 1)
grayscale_frame = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
median_blur_frame = cv2.medianBlur(grayscale_frame, 5)
gaussian_blur_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(median_blur_frame, (5, 5), 0)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gaussian_blur_frame, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=45, param1=75, param2=14,
                           minRadius=40, maxRadius=45)
for circle in circles[0]:
    print(circle)
    cv2.circle(img, (int(circle[0]), int(circle[1])), int(circle[2]), (255, 255, 255), 5)
cv2.imshow("Frame", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Or you could try converting the image to a different color space to segment the pool table

Comment: @JeruLuke Thanks for the prompt response! Would you mind writing an answer to describe how I could do so?

Comment: Your go to place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/

Comment: Try adjusting param1 and param2

Comment: @StackOverflow did you try segmenting the pool and proceed?

Comment: @JeruLuke Yep, that's the approach I'm going with. Thank you so much!