# OpenCV Blue Color Ranges Detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am extracting the blue color using OpenCV inRange(), and the code is written in C++.

My problem is my range doesn't cover the varying shades of blue, for example [image: 1st Image] blue color was extracted perfectly as shown [image: 1st image result]On the other hand, [image: 2nd Image] was not extracted as shown [image: 2nd image result]

The masking code

```
+ (UIImage *)detectFourCorners:(UIImage *)image{

cv::Mat mat;
UIImageToMat(image, mat);

// Convert input image to into BGR
cv::Mat bgr_image;
cv::cvtColor(mat, bgr_image, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);

// Convert input image to HSV
cv::Mat hsv_image;
cv::cvtColor(bgr_image, hsv_image, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

cv::Mat mask;

// original
cv::inRange( hsv_image, cv::Scalar(100,150,0), cv::Scalar(140,255,255), mask);

cv::Mat result_blue;
cv::bitwise_and(mat,mat,result_blue,mask);

return MatToUIImage(result_blue); }
```

I believe I'm not covering all the needed ranges of blue, but I don't know how to get my own ranges. If anyone could help, it would be appreciated !

Comment: Try creating a color tracker similar to this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/

Comment: To be honest, I'm having trouble telling that those squares are blue. If a person can't do it, how can a computer?

Comment: I increased the range for the saturation (`S`) chanel to 100..255 (instead of 150..255) and the second image get a lot better result. It might introduce fasle positives with other images, but anyway how did you calibrate your range thresholds ?

Comment: Im still going to do some tests, but at this point changing "S" channel to 90 solved the problem!, I wasn't able to understand the ranges-basically brute forcing them- but after checking @JeruLuke attached answer it makes a lot of sense now!, THANK YOU ALL