# Process finished with exit code 139 while Open CV Trackbar excercise

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I am having an exit code 139 while running a trackbar training program, My code is as follows:
'''

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def empty():
    pass

path = "Resources/cards.png"
#Create trackbars for adjustment
cv2.namedWindow("TrackBars")
cv2.resizeWindow("TrackBars",640,240)
cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Min","TrackBars",0,179,empty)
img = cv2.imread(path)

imgHSV =cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.imshow("Original img",img)
cv2.imshow("HSV img",imgHSV)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

'''
anyone couldgive advise? I am running it on PyCharm CE on MacOS :)

I attach image, it does load. however when threshold bars are clicked it crashes.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0hal.jpg)

Comment: It compiles and works, however when I click the trackbar it closes and indicates the error :(

Comment: Tried to run it on python 3.10.5 on PyCharm. with current version had to pip install. Upgrade affected trackbar graphics (now available on night mode)  Checked other forums to see if any similar error occured. However, problem persists, at the toggle of the trackbar python collapses with said error. t

Comment: Which opencv version currently u re using

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/59906154#59906154

Comment: Thank you man, I tried the suggested code but same condition is happening :(

Comment: I am using OpenCV 4.6.0.66

Comment: I modified the python interpreter and made it work. it became a little slow but functional.