# Detecting a grid with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image of a [goban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goban) (example below). I want to detect the grid of the playing area to create an (x, y) coordinate system of the board. To start I am trying to just detect the lines on the board:

```
def find_lines(filename):
    gray = cv2.imread(str(filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    kernel_size = 5
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (kernel_size, kernel_size), 0)

    low_threshold = 50
    high_threshold = 150
    edges = cv2.Canny(blur, low_threshold, high_threshold)
    rho = 1  # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
    theta = np.pi / 180  # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
    threshold = 15  # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
    min_line_length = 50  # minimum number of pixels making up a line
    max_line_gap = 20  # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), min_line_length, max_line_gap)

    line_image = np.zeros((*gray.shape, 3))
    for line in lines:
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
            cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),5)
    return line_image


def main(filename):
    lines = find_lines(filename)
    cv2.imwrite('lines.jpg'), lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

This gives me a good image of the outline of the board, but I want to get just the grid. Part of the difficulty is that the grid lines have a width and `HoughLinesP()` is giving me the outline of these lines. Also, it is giving me multiple segments along each grid line when I want the (x, y) coordinates at the top and bottom or left and right of each grid line. The `lines` variable in `find_lines()` has dimensions `(1411, 1, 4)`, but I only want the 38 grid lines. What can I do from here to get just the endpoints of the grid lines?

[image]

Comment: "*This gives me a good image of the outline of the board*", if I were you, I would use `cv2.PerspectiveTransform(source_coordinates, destination_coordinates)` and crop the board in a square shape then you can resize it.

Comment: @Bilal This might be an XY problem. Part of my motivation to find the grid in the image is to determine the `source_coordinates` for a perspective transformation. Do you have an alternative suggestion for doing that?

Comment: @Bilal Oh, your suggested dupe might be the solution here. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @Bilal The code from the accepted answer appears to give the results I want. Thanks. Now to move to the harder version of this problem when there are stones on the board.

Comment: ...and a partial board

Comment: "*partial board*", [HSV Segmentaion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59906154) is useful to detect the wooden board and then the borders, and if you can do so you can apply the former approach again.

Comment: @Bilal Thanks for the link. I'll check it out after I figure out some other things with a complete board.