How to detect entities (sprites) in a screenshot of a 2D game using OpenCV?
I am creating a program to detect mobs in a pixel rpg. I tried to detect the contours of mobs using OpenCV color filtering because mobs are yellow-red while the background is gray-black, but I can't find the HSV range, and I'm also not sure about the contour filtering parameters by size and aspect ratio.
from PIL import ImageOps, Image, ImageGrab
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
import win32gui
import pyautogui

WINDOW_SUBSTRING = "Game"

def get_window_info():
    window_info = {}
    win32gui.EnumWindows(set_window_coordinates, window_info)
    return window_info


def set_window_coordinates(hwnd, window_info):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if WINDOW_SUBSTRING in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
            x = rect[0]
            y = rect[1]
            w = rect[2] - x
            h = rect[3] - y
            window_info['x'] = x
            window_info['y'] = y
            window_info['width'] = w
            window_info['height'] = h
            window_info['name'] = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)

def get_screen(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    box = (x1, y1+31, x2, y2-68)
    screen = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    img = array(screen.getdata(), dtype=uint8).reshape((screen.size[1], screen.size[0], 3))
    return img

def find_contours():
    window_info = get_window_info()
    img = get_screen(
        window_info["x"],
        window_info["y"],
        window_info["x"] + window_info["width"],
        window_info["y"] + window_info["height"]
    )

    img[0:77, 0:182] = (0, 0, 0)

    lower_range = np.array([10, 150, 150])
    upper_range = np.array([25, 255, 255])
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = gray.astype(np.uint8)
    gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    monsters = []
    for contour in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        if w*h > 300 and w/h > 0.8 and w/h < 1.2:
            monsters.append((x, y))
    for monster in monsters:
        print(f"Monster: {monster}")

    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("Contours", cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    find_contours()

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()

Initially, I tried to just look for contours in the image, but this led to dozens of extra tons. All objects in the game consist of different pixel patterns. It got better after using color filtering, but the program still doesn't find mobs.
Original:
Original
Best result:

Mask:

Desired result:
Desired result
I marked  all the mobs in the last image.

Maybe you could add another annotated picture because I cannot see any red and white mobs (whatever a mob is) in your rocket-propelled grenade‍♂️

Can you also share your source image and desired result ?

A simple approach would be to try something like template matching. If you have access to the asset files or you can create 'screenshots' of your mobs you can then search your image for them.

those are sprite graphics. I second the template matching.

I agree with template matching. There is a good tutorial in official docs here. I think you'll probably want a masked template because backgrounds probably can vary. Be warned that template matching will fail if the colors change much or the size is different.

I think color filtering is the easies method here you should choose your min and max better.It seems you need yellow and red color so use H range as [0,40] also your S range and V range  seems good to get rid of the background and the brown dragons. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv , for more detailed HSV explanations.
